# How to use ORDER BY in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

basically I am building a Web app for school and its using Telegram Bot API to send messages to my contacts. On left side of my web page I have contacts div and there is list of all contacts from table in MySQL. Everything works perfect except they are not ordered asc by name.

Controller

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

@Autowired
private ContactsService contactsService;

@GetMapping("/")
public String allContacts(HttpServletRequest request) {
    request.setAttribute("contacts", contactsService.findAll());
    request.setAttribute("mode", "MODE_CONTACTS");
    return "index";
}

@RequestMapping("/input")
public String input() {
    return("input");
}
}
```

Repository

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import totelegram.model.Contacts;
public interface ContactsRepository extends CrudRepository<Contacts, Integer>{
}
```

Service

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class ContactsService {

private final ContactsRepository contactsRepository;

public ContactsService(ContactsRepository contactsRepository) {
    super();
    this.contactsRepository = contactsRepository;
}

//@Query("select * from contacts order by name asc")
public List<Contacts> findAll(){
    List<Contacts> contacts = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Contacts contact : contactsRepository.findAll()) {
        contacts.add(contact);
    }
    return contacts;
}
}
```

Model

```
@Entity(name = "contacts")
public class Contacts implements Serializable{
```

And basically it just has id,name,phone_number, getters/setters, toString. You can see in Service one comment which is exactly something I can't figure out. Where that @Query needs to be so when you display table on website you get them ordered.

Answer from Abinash Ghosh solved a problem. But others were helpful too. 
Thank you all for help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `JpaRepository` and JPA method naming feature for `Order by`

Repository

```
public interface ContactsRepository extends JpaRepository<Contacts, Integer> {
    public List<Contacts> findAllByOrderByNameAsc();
}
```

Service

```
public List<Contacts> findAll(){
    List<Contacts> contacts = contactsRepository.findAllByOrderByNameAsc();
    return contacts;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code for desc order .
You can do for asc by **Sort.Direction.ASC** and also 
change field name as per need. I have used "id" here.
It should work fine.

```
public List<Contacts> findAll(){
    List<Contacts> contacts = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Contacts contact : contactsRepository.findAll(sortByIdDesc())) {
        contacts.add(contact);
    }
    return contacts;
}

 private Sort sortByIdDesc() {
        return new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "id");
 }
```

For your problem , solution is :

```
public List<Contacts> findAll(){
    List<Contacts> contacts = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Contacts contact : contactsRepository.findAll(sortByNameAsc())) {
        contacts.add(contact);
    }
    return contacts;
}

 private Sort sortByNameAsc() {
        return new Sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "name");
 }
```

Comment: he question is how to "order by name asc"

Comment: I have answered for both ASC and DESC.  Check edited answer please.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to the answer from Md Shifatul Isalm you could also create a Repository mehtod like:

```
List<Contacts> findAllOrderByNameAsc();
```

Btw you don't need the additional ArrayList. Just return the values from the Repository:

```
return contactsRepository.findAllOrderByNameAsc();
```